# Trying to run Gemma on Kaggle and got issue 'keras_nlp.models' has no attribute 'GemmaCausalLM'

Tags: python, kaggle, gemma

I'm trying to run Gemma on Keras with this model https://www.kaggle.com/models/keras/gemma/frameworks/keras/variations/gemma_instruct_7b_en
And I'm reproducing the Example available on "Model Card" on above page.
When I run this code:

```
gemma_lm = keras_nlp.models.GemmaCausalLM.from_preset("gemma_instruct_7b_en")
gemma_lm.generate("Keras is a", max_length=30)

# Generate with batched prompts.
gemma_lm.generate(["Keras is a", "I want to say"], max_length=30)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 gemma_lm = keras_nlp.models.GemmaCausalLM.from_preset("gemma_instruct_7b_en")
      2 gemma_lm.generate("Keras is a", max_length=30)
      4 # Generate with batched prompts.
AttributeError: module 'keras_nlp.models' has no attribute 'GemmaCausalLM'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting the kernel.

Note that the same behavior occurs with the 2B Gemma model, i.e. `gemma_lm = keras_nlp.models.GemmaCausalLM.from_preset("gemma_2b_en")`.

I am not sure why restarting the kernel works, but it's worth noting that this doesn't happen in Google Colab.

Comment: restarting kernel works, thanks! For future wanderers, to restart kernel right click on the code cell and in context menu chose 'restart kernel' (try different cell if it does not work for the first time, for me the right cell was where I have all imports)